# Is barium sulfate soluble in dilute mineral acid?

Tags: acid-base, solubility, elemental-analysis

I have read that $\ce{BaSO4}$ is soluble in $\ce{HCl}$ , but I am not sure whether this works for dilute acid as well.

The reaction is -
$\ce{BaSO4 + 2 HCl ->BaCl2 + H2SO4}$

Comment: H2SO4 does not form, $\ce{HSO4-}$ does. And you have to add the physical states as you are documenting how a substance goes from solid to aqueous. Another hint: chloride is a spectator ion.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is to have an acid with such a high $\ce{H+}$ activity that in large extent shifts the below reaction to the left :
$$\ce{  HSO4-  + H2O <=> SO4^2- + H3O+ } \\ K_\mathrm{a2}=1.0 \cdot  10^{-2}$$

Then activity of sulphate ions from dissolution of $\ce{BaSO4}$ is decreased by the equilibrium reaction and the solubility increases.

$$\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{s}&=a_{\ce{Ba^2+}}\cdot a_{\ce{SO4^2-}}=1.1\times 10^{-10}\\
\frac{K_\mathrm{a2}}{a_{\ce{H+}}}&=\frac{a_{\ce{SO4^2-}}}{a_{\ce{HSO4^-}}}\\
\end{align}$$

The  effective solubility product 
$$K_\mathrm{s,ef}=K_\mathrm{s} \cdot    \frac{a_{\ce{H+}}}{K_\mathrm{a2}}$$

Note that despite [activity coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_coefficient?wprov=sfla1) {gamma} decrease with increasing ionic strength, for concentrated acids this tendency reverses and [raises very rapidly](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/13%3A_Acid-Base_Equilibria/11.2%3A_Strong_Monoprotic_Acids_and_Bases)

```
[HCl]  Gamma
0.0005 0.975
0.01 0.904
0.1 0.796
1 0.809
2 1.01
5 2.38
10 10.44
12 17.25
```

Therefore, $a_{\ce{H+}}$ of 10 M HCl = 104.4.

$$K_\mathrm{s,ef}=K_\mathrm{s} \cdot    \frac{104.4}{K_\mathrm{a2}}\\=1.1\cdot 10^{-10}\cdot 1.044\cdot 10^4=1.148\cdot 10^{-6} \mathrm{~ mol^2 L^{-2}}$$

Solubility would be then $ M \cdot \sqrt{K_\mathrm{s,ef}}=233.4 \cdot 0.001072=0.25\mathrm{~g/L}$

Conclusion: The $\ce{BaSO4}$ solubility in concentrated $\ce{HCl}$ is limited, in diluted one is very low. The solubility in concentrated sulphuric acid would be much higher, as $a_{\ce{H+}}$ would be very high.